# Is there a way to run a function off a string?

Tags: c#, function, delegates

So say I have a string called fun. Its text is "myFun". I want to run a function called myFun:

```
private void myFun()
{
  //stuff
}
```

Is there a way to do this so I can run it based on the text of the string? Maybe like this:

```
myFun + ();
```

Clearly that won't work, but is there something that will?

Comment: What's the string? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding what you want to do. Maybe post some code with your string "myFun" and what you want to do with it.

Comment: So if I have a string called fun, I want to be able to run a function based on its text, so I could run function funny(), funiful(), epic(), etc, based on what it's text is (funny, funiful, epic, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given I have this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    private void myFun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

I can call this code:

```
var fun = "myFun";
var foo = new Foo();
foo
    .GetType()
    .GetMethod(
        fun,
        BindingFlags.NonPublic
            | BindingFlags.Instance
            | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod)
    .Invoke(foo, new object[] { });
```

That does what you want, I think.

Answer (score 2):

global members

```
delegate void aFunction();
```

constructor or init function

```
Dictionary<string, aFunction> myfunctions = new Dictionary<string, aFunction>();
myfunctions.Add("myFun", myFun);
```

call your function from the string

```
myfunctions["myFun"].Invoke();
```

Comment: +1. I think using a Dictionary of string - delegates/funcs/actions is the right way, but only if you know that the signature will be the same for all cases. Otherwise, a simple `if` statement calling the different methods would work, passing the parameters you need on each case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with reflection. Assuming `myFun` is a member of the same class you're calling it from:

```
var t = typeof( this );
t.InvokeMember(myFun,
               BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
               null, this, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use reflection, as Alex suggests; or if you don't need to be able to run any given function, you could define a `Dictionary` that would map between names and functions.

Comment: like a `Dictionary<string, Action>` ?

Comment: Yep. Or whatever type is most appropriate for your particular functions.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but you could accomplish *almost* what you want with extension methods.

Define a public static class and add methods as follows...

```
public static string ny(this string str)
{
    //.. do something
}
```

Then import your extension class and you can call the function directly on your string object.

```
myFun.ny();
```

The key to the extension method is the *this* keyword added to the argument.  Again, probably not exactly what you are looking for, but it should work.